# How do i solve this illegalState Exception on .setOnClickListener

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

Please, help me. I have seen many solutions but none is working for me!
I am new to the Android Studio and I couldn't figure out what is the actual error.  When I am running this code the app is crashing and giving me this error. First i sort out the Null pointer exception and after I've solved it app is giving me illegal state exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: findViewById(R.id.request_blood_button) must not be null
        at com.example.lifesaviour.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:39)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
```

This is my ativity_main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:src="@drawable/slifetext"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <GridLayout
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:rowCount="3"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardElevation="6dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                android:layout_margin="12dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/request_blood_button"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/requestblood">
                    </ImageView>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:text="Request Blood"
                        android:textColor="#000000">

                    </TextView>

                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</GridLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my MainActivity.kt file

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var request_blood_imageView: ImageView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        request_blood_imageView = findViewById(R.id.request_blood_button) //Error here line:39

request_blood_imageView.setOnClickListener {

            val request_blood_intent = Intent(this, RequestBlood::class.java)
            startActivity(request_blood_intent)
   }
}
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thankyou

Comment: You need to call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` before trying to find a view.

Comment: Sorry for that that was a copy-paste mistake. I have added that in my code!..I'll edit my code

Comment: Update your code here.

Comment: I removed some drawables, added CardView library and built a project. It ran.

Comment: Download https://ufile.io/45j004sh.

Comment: CardView library means dependency to be added in the build.gradle file ?

Comment: It says request_blood_button does not exist in activity_main

Comment: But i have added that using its id

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of this layout for different configurations? Maybe it's missing in one of them.

Comment: Can you check the name of your layout file?

Comment: Oh damnnn! 
that was the most silliest mistake. By nowhere my app has made 2 layouts although I was just changing on the same one and its running the second layout which is same like the one i was working on but its has no button . that's why its giving me this error.

Comment: Now the problem is solved
Thank you so much, everyone.